# Add Custom Font Size and Trigger Icon Size to PrimeNG Dropdown

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, primeng

I have been working with PrimeNG as the UI library to an Angular TypeScript application I have been developing and I have been having trouble customizing the font size styling and the dropdown trigger icon styling of the PrimeNG dropdown that I have put together. It seems the styling documentation for PrimeNG is rather vague on how to customize it.

No matter how I try to adjust it, the font size does not change within the dropdown. I am not sure if I should use the inline style in html, a property in TypeScript, or override the PrimeNG CSS styling to accomplish this. This also goes for the Dropdown Trigger icon.

Here is my HTML, TypeScript, and CSS.

```
<p-dropdown [options]="heights" [style]="{'font-size':'12px'}" [(ngModel)]="height" (ngModelChange)="adjustHeight()">
</p-dropdown>
```

```
heights: SelectItem[] = [
    {label: 'Table Size: Small', value: 'Small'},
    {label: 'Table Size: Large', value: 'Large'}
];
```

```
.p-dropdown {
    font-size: 12px !important;
}

.p-dropdown-trigger {
    font-size 12px !important
}
```

Update:
Using what was suggested below and a simple adjustment to the style class referred to in PrimeNG I was able to change the font size of the text in a p-dropdown with:

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-dropdown-label {
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :-

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-dropdown {
    font-size: 12px !important;
}

:host ::ng-deep .p-dropdown-trigger {
    font-size 12px !important
}
```

Comment: I was able to change the font size of the dropdown text using :host ::ng-deep .p-dropdown-label { .... } , but for some reason the dropdown trigger icon sizing won't change even with this method.

Comment: @NicFalcione can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-mrtijv?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: You should replace `.p-dropdown-trigger` with `.p-dropdown-trigger-icon`.

Comment: didn't work....